# Vertical Japanese text not center aligning on IE11

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-11, centering, cjk

I am using vertical Japanese text for the first time and I have gotten it to work as i want on newer browsers, however the client is using IE11 and the text does not center align on IE11.

The issue can be seen on the page below if you scroll down to after the portfolio items.

https://eiken-net.com/construction-examples/

[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VESuW.jpg)

I am not a developer and only have a basic understanding of html/css, on top of that I am using a wordpress theme so it is quite tricky.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Answer (score 0):

In 'IE', 'ms-writing-mode' and 'margin: auto; 'analysis is inconsistent with other browsers, you can manually use' position' in the middle.

```css
.vc_custom_heading_wrap {
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

.vertical-heading-2 {
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  font-family: serif;
  height: 310px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 92px);
}
```

```html
<div class="vc_custom_heading_wrap">
  <div class="heading-text el-text vertical-heading-2">
    <h1 class="fontsize-263531">
      <span>自信があります。</span>
      <span>無垢の家を</span>
      <span>比べてください。</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>
```

[Use Internet explorer to access](http://jsrun.net/qz2Kp)

[or to codepen](https://codepen.io/rudyjoy/pen/yLYGXRg)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the `margin: auto;` CSS property, try to change the `margin: auto;` to `margin-left: 50%; margin-right: 50%;`

Code as below:

```
.vertical-heading-2 {
    -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    font-family: "游明朝", YuMincho, "ヒラギノ明朝 ProN W3", "Hiragino Mincho ProN", "HG明朝E", "ＭＳ Ｐ明朝", "ＭＳ 明朝", serif;
    height: 310px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Also, you could add the following CSS style at the end of the web page CSS style.

```
.vertical-heading-2 { 
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%; 
}
```

Output in IE browser:
[image]